# How to search index of an object in jagged array?

Tags: c#, arrays, jagged-arrays

This is my code 
I need to find the index of an object by matching the char value in the constructor.

```
Transition[][] transitions = new Transition[3][]
{
    new Transition[] {new Transition ('+',1), new Transition('-',1 ) , new Transition('0',1), new Transition('1', 1), new Transition('2', 1) } ,
    new Transition[] {new Transition('0', 2), new Transition ('1',2) , new Transition('2',2) },
    new Transition[] {new Transition ('0',2) , new Transition( '1',2 ), new Transition('2',2) }
};
```

Comment: But all arrays contain a `Transition` with the same char `0`. You want to find all indexes or only the first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 index values for each char-match. And there are multiple possible results.

So your method to determine indexes should look like

```
public static IEnumerable<Tuple<int, int>> GetIndexes(Transition[][] Items, char SearchChar)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Items.Length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < Items[i].Length; j++)
        {
            if (Items[i][j].charItem == SearchChar) // charItem  is the name of your property
            {
                yield return new Tuple<int, int>(i, j);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var Result = GetIndexes(transitions, '1'); //(0,3)(1,1)(2,1)
```